# show binary data in vc++ component

Tags: visual-c++, binary-data

i am developing my GUI in visual c++ and i want to show binary data in rich edit or similar text editing control so please can any one help me how can i achieve this?(Like if we open any binary file in notepad++).

EDIT:
 all ASCII characters i want to show in GUI.

for example:

[image]

please help me.

Comment: "Binary data" and "text control" doesn't seem to match very well. Do you mean you want to edit it like a hex editor?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: yes,but actually i am developing client server application using visual c++(GUI) and c++. now i want to show binary data in any control which is sent by client/server. is this any way to do this please help me...

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this.

1. If you already have the format of the binary data, just output the structures with field names and values:

   ```
   Data:
       Field1: Value1
       Field2: Value2
   ```

   The above can be from a structure like:

   ```
   struct Data
   {
       int field1;
       int field2;
   }
   ```
2. You can format the data like a hex editor, something like this:

   ```
   0000 xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx ........
   0008 xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx ........
   ```

   The first number is the offset into the binary data, each "xx" is a byte in hexadecimal, and each "." is a printable representation of the corresponding byte (if it is printable, otherwise the custom is to print a dot.)

Comment: but i want to display it in visual c++ control(GUI), how can i do that?

Comment: means all ASCII character i want to display in GUI.

Comment: @yogeshpatel You format it as a string like in my answer, then put the text from that string into the text control like for any other text. For that you have to read the documentation for e.g. [`CStatic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98kd6f7(v=vs.100).aspx) or [`CEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7yhsd2b(v=vs.100).aspx) if you are using MFC.